# iOS strange Statusbar colors

Tags: swift, ios13

We have a TabBar application and we want to change the Statusbar style to lightContent on one tab.

We use this code to change it.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

But when I switch the tab, only the right side of the statusbar changes it's color to white. The left side stays black. See screenshot.

After about one second the left side also changes to white.

Any Idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks,
Urkman

[image: statusbar colors]

Comment: try to add this line of code setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik already tried this... no change :(

Comment: ok, than try this WorkAround override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

Comment: Still no change... And UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle is deprecated since iOS9...

Comment: do you have `View controller-based status bar appearance` property in your plist?

Comment: yes, sure we have

Comment: if it is YES nothing happens

Comment: is dump option bu try to restar the device and you may get off that nasty bug